# jQuery selector reference to self

Tags: jquery

Simple question:

How do I refer to self without using `$.each()` for example when I want to set `html()` to own attribute?

```
$('*[rel]').html($(this).attr('rel')); // nope
$('*[rel]').html($(self).attr('rel')); // nah
$('*[rel]').html($(sender).attr('rel')); // undefined
$('*[rel]').html($(target).attr('rel')); // still undefined
$('*[rel]').html($(???).attr('rel')); // this isn't even correct syntax
$('*[rel]').html($(beer).attr('rel')); // well that would be tasty
$('*[rel]').html($(woman).attr('rel')); // not in this life
$('*[rel]').html($(god help me!).attr('rel')); // He probably doesn't even know how to use a computer
$('*[rel]').html($(i give up).attr('rel')); // unexpected... o'rly?
```

Comment: _He probably doesn't even know how to use a computer_ :)

Comment: Vote up for the question itself, if only for the humor in it...  :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[You can pass a function instead of a a string.](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml)

```
$('[rel]').html(function() {
    return $(this).attr('rel');
});
```

The reason why all of your examples don't work is because in each case your code executes long before the selector has been evaluated. This is something you really need to understand - it's even more relevant when callbacks are involved e.g. for AJAX or timers: When you put code somewhere it's executed at this point. So `foo(some code here)` will **always** execute the code that's part of the function argument no matter what `foo` does. The only reason to avoid this is passing a function that contains this code - that was the function expression is evaluated (which evaluates to a callable function). Then the actual function (which obviously needs to expect a callable instead of a simple value) can invoke the passed function whenever it's appropriate.

Comment: Ok. I do understand that js is based on callbacks, but was sure that long, long ago, in a land far, far away, there lived a beautiful young girl... yes, and she had computer in which on old, old version of j, j, jQuery `sender` or `self` worked. But I may be wrong about the girl, when I was young every girl was beautiful.

Comment: Yeah I think that girl made you think weird things - it's technically impossible that what you suggested ever worked that way.