# How to avoid repeating jQuery selector when setting value to it

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

So, I want to set the html text of an element from an attribute already set on that same element so I do the following:

```
$('#el').html($('#el').val());
```

How can I avoid the repeating $('#el')? I tried with 'this' but it didn't work.
Thanks! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery selector reference to self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834431/jquery-selector-reference-to-self)

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen ye it didn't pop in the suggestions, or at least I didn't see it, ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a local variable of the jQuery selection:

```
let el = $('#el');

el.html(el.val());
```

Comment: This looks like optimal solution to me.

Answer (score 1):

reading [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) you can use as callback, and the use this:

`$('#el').html(function(){return $(this).val()})`;

Comment: lacking `return`

Comment: @ShadowFiend tks

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón you haven't fixed the return statement

Comment: still wrong.. `this this` instead of `return this.val()`

Comment: jajajajaj @ShadowFiend, 
the rush is bad

Comment: need to fix 'this' to be '$(this)' as well, thnx tho